# Count number of occurrences of a term in entire list, and attach with corresponding variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, tuples

I have a list which has 3 elements for each item, and it looks like this:

```
list_A = [(['apple','orange','banana'], 2,0.1),
          (['grape', 'water', 'fountain'], 4, 0.2),
          (['apple', 'grape', 'banana',], 6, 0.3),
          (['orange', 'water', 'apple',], 8, 0.4),...]
```

First, I would like to count every **term's occurrence** in entire list, then attach with their **corresponding variables** to form a new list.

For example(**see first line**), Number of occurrences for term ('**apple**') is **3** in entire list, then **its two corresponding variables** is attached together. The result should be like this:

```
new_list = [('apple', 3, 2, 0.1),
            ('apple', 3, 6, 0.3),
            ('apple', 3, 8, 0.4),
            ('orange', 2, 2, 0.1),
            ('banana', 2, 2, 0.1),
            ('grape', 2, 4, 0.2),
            ('water', 2, 4, 0.2),......]
```

I've been trying and tweaking to get it with this function`Counter(x[0] for elem in each)` using `from collections import Counter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(sum((row[0] for row in list_A), []))

for row in list_A:
  print [(el, counts[el]) + row[1:] for el in row[0]]
```

Here, `sum((row[0] for row in list_A), [])` merges the string sublists into one. The rest should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Much appreciated for your quick response!

Answer (score 1):

This version use a functional approach to extract the strings from the tuple's lists.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain
from operator import itemgetter

list_A = [
    (['apple', 'orange', 'banana'], 2, 0.1),
    (['grape', 'water', 'fountain'], 4, 0.2),
    (['apple', 'grape', 'banana',], 6, 0.3),
    (['orange', 'water', 'apple',], 8, 0.4),
]

counts = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(itemgetter(0), list_A)))

new_list = []
for row in list_A:
    head, tail = row[0], row[1:]
    for u in head:
        new_list.append((u, counts[u]) + tail)

new_list.sort()
for row in new_list:
    print(row)
```

**output**

```
('apple', 3, 2, 0.1)
('apple', 3, 6, 0.3)
('apple', 3, 8, 0.4)
('banana', 2, 2, 0.1)
('banana', 2, 6, 0.3)
('fountain', 1, 4, 0.2)
('grape', 2, 4, 0.2)
('grape', 2, 6, 0.3)
('orange', 2, 2, 0.1)
('orange', 2, 8, 0.4)
('water', 2, 4, 0.2)
('water', 2, 8, 0.4)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Comment: @htetmyet No worries. I started work on it, but then I got interrupted. When I got back NPE had posted their solution, but I figured you may be interested in seeing a slightly different approach anyway. :)